# Incorrect Key for decrypting web service response

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, ws-security, x509

I am working on a WCF client to consume a third party web service over which I have no control. It works with a custom binding and WS Security. No app.config, all through code. I can successfully send requests and receive responses. However, it seems .Net cannot decrypt the service responses, so I have to do it manually. I have implemented a custom encoder and overriden the `ReadMessage` method. I have access to the raw SOAP response. I have seen code in MSDN as well as a blog where they explain how to decrypt the response. I read the oasis specifications for the response xml schema. The response contains a reference to the x509 certificate that has the private key necessary to decrypt the session key, so then the body can be decrypted. According to the documentation of the service I am trying to consume, and pretty much everywhere I've read, I should use the private key of the certificate I used to  sign my request, but I get an Exception saying the key is incorrect. I then tried every possible certificate with a private key in all my certificate stores to see if one of them would successfully decrypt the message but all of them failed. If I understand it right, this means the service expects me to decrypt the message with a private key I don't have. I'm rather new to WCF and web services themselves, so I might be missing something.

Do you know what could be happening? Or maybe I am understanding something wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The way I see it, you ask the vendor for a working example of how to consume their service. That should be enough to figure out the rest. You are working with a third party piece of software and they are in the best position to help you. There is no shame in asking for a working example as web service interop is know to have been problematic.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. Although I don't think they have a working example, I can at least try to ask them what private key should I use.

Comment: There are different versions of WS security and from my experience they work differently in different versions of soap. Last year I had to consume a java soap web service with ws security from .net. It basically landed on my lap because the client could not do it themselves and needed help. It took me more than a week to getting it to work and I've seen all sort of exceptions including inability to decrypt

Comment: Luckily for me I was able to get my hands on java client test harness the vendor build so by examining the contents of soap envelops flowing back in forward I was able to make necessary configuration changes in the .net client that finally worked. Yes, you do have to exchange certificates for all this to work. And yes, the whole thing is usually complicated, especially when client and server are on different technology stacks. Good luck.